# Getting good mixing with many input datafiles in tensorflow

Tags: python, neural-network, binaryfiles, tensorflow

I'm working with tensorflow hoping to train a deep CNN to do move prediction for the game Go. The dataset I created consists of 100,000 binary data files, where each datafile corresponds to a recorded game and contains roughly 200 training samples (one for each move in the game). I believe it will be very important to get good mixing when using SGD. I'd like my batches to contain samples from different games AND samples from different stages of the games. So for example simply reading one sample from the start of 100 files and shuffling isn't good b/c those 100 samples will all be the first move of each game.

I have read the tutorial on feeding data from files but I'm not sure if their provided libraries do what I need. If I were to hard code it myself I would basically initialize a bunch of file pointers to random locations within each file and then pull samples from random files, incrementing the file pointers accordingly.

So, my question is does tensorflow provide this sort of functionality or would it be easier to write my own code for creating batches?

Answer (score 11):

Yes - what you want is to use a combination of two things.
(Note that this answer was written for TensorFlow v1, and some of the functionality has been replaced by the new tf.data pipelines; I've updated the answers to point to the v1 compat versions of things, but if you're coming to this answer for new code, please consult [`tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data) instead.)

First, randomly shuffle the order in which you input your datafiles, by reading from them using a [`tf.train.string_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/string_input_producer) with `shuffle=True` that feeds into whatever input method you use (if you can put your examples into tf.Example proto format, that's easy to use with `parse_example`).  To be very clear, you put the list of filenames in the `string_input_producer` and then read them with another method such as `read_file`, etc.

Second, you need to mix at a finer granularity.  You can accomplish this by feeding the input examples into a [`tf.train.shuffle_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/shuffle_batch) node with a large capacity and large value of `min_after_dequeue`.  One particularly nice way is to use a `shuffle_batch_join` that receives input from multiple files, so that you get a lot of mixing.  Set the capacity of the batch big enough to mix well without exhausting your RAM.  Tens of thousands of examples usually works pretty well.

Keep in mind that the batch functions add a `QueueRunner` to the `QUEUE_RUNNERS` collection, so you need to run [`tf.train.start_queue_runners()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/start_queue_runners)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that a string_input_producer with 100% capacity and `shuffle=True` will yield perfect mixing, without the need for batch shuffling?

Comment: Links are broken

Comment: Thanks! I've udpated the answer to (a) point to the new tf.data API that should be used for new code; and (b) point to the v1.compat versions of the docs for the functions referenced in the answer. Appreciate the nudge.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is not a problem to do some preprocessing and create one file out of all the files you have. For this type of games, where the history is not important and the position determines everything your dataset can consist just from `position -> next_move`.

---

For a more broad case TF provides everything to allow the shuffling you want. There are two types shuffling which serve different purposes and shuffle different things:

- [`tf.train.string_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) *shuffle: Boolean. If true, the strings are randomly shuffled within each epoch.*. So if you have a few files `['file1', 'file2', ..., 'filen']` this randomly selects a file from this list. If case of false, the files follow one after each other.
- [`tf.train.shuffle_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch) *Creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors.* So it takes `batch_size` tensors from your queue (you will need to create a queue with `tf.train.start_queue_runners` ) and shuffles them.

Comment: Links are broken