# Tensorflow Tutorial: Duplicated Shuffling in the Input Pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the [Tensorflow reading data tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#batching) an example input pipeline is given. In that pipeline the data is shuffled twice, inside the `string_input_producer` as well as in the `shuffle batch generator`. Here is the code:

```
def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs=None):
  # Fist shuffle in the input pipeline
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
      filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)

  example, label = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)
  min_after_dequeue = 10000
  capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
  # Second shuffle as part of the batching. 
  # Requiring min_after_dequeue preloaded images
  example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
      min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)

  return example_batch, label_batch
```

Does the second shuffle serve any useful purpose? The shuffle batch generator has the disadvantage that `min_after_dequeue` examples are always stored pre-loaded in the memory to allow a useful shuffle. I do have image data which is quite heavy in memory consumption. That is why I am considering to use a `normal batch generator` instead. Is there any advantage in shuffling the data twice?

Edit: Additional Question, why is the `string_input_producer` initialized only with default capacity of 32? Wouldn't it be advantageous to have a multiple of batch_size as capacity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - this is a common pattern, and it's shown in the most general way.  The `string_input_producer` shuffles the order in which the data files are read.  Each data file typically contains many examples, for efficiency.  (Reading a million small files is very slow;  it's better to read 1000 large files with 1000 examples each.)

Therefore, the examples from the files are read into a shuffling queue, where they are shuffled at a much finer granularity, so that examples from the same file aren't always trained in the same order, and to get mixing across the input files.

For more details, see [Getting good mixing with many input datafiles in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258043/getting-good-mixing-with-many-input-datafiles-in-tensorflow/34258214#34258214)

If your files each contain only one input example, you don't need to shuffle multiple times and could get away with only a `string_input_producer`, but note that you still will likely benefit from having a queue that holds a few images after reading, so that you can overlap the inputting and training of your network.  The `queue_runner` for a `batch` or `shuffle_batch` will run in a separate thread, ensuring that the I/O is happening in the background and that images are always available for training.  And, of course, it's typically nice for speed to create minibatches to train on.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the shuffles serves different purposes and shuffle different things:

- [`tf.train.string_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) *shuffle: Boolean. If true, the strings are randomly shuffled within each epoch.*. So if you have a few files `['file1', 'file2', ..., 'filen']` this randomly selects a file from this list. If case of false, the files follow one after each other.
- [`tf.train.shuffle_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch) *Creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors.* So it takes `batch_size` tensors from your queue `read_my_file_format` and shuffles them.

Because both shuffles do different things, there is an advantage to shuffle the data two times. Even if you use a batch of 256 images, and each image is 256x256 pixels, you will consume less than 100 Mb of memory. If at some point you will see memory problems, you can try decreasing your batch size.

Regarding the default capacity - it is [model specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44857104/1090562). It makes sense to have it bigger than batch_size and to make sure it is never empty during the training.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the additional question, the `string_input_producer` returns a queue containing the **name of the files** containing the samples, not the samples themselves. This filenames are then used by `shuffle_batch` to load the data. The number of samples that are loaded is thus related to the `capacity` parameter of the **`shuffle_batch`** function, not `string_input_producer`.