# what is the argument "capacity" for in tf.train.string_input_producer()

Tags: tensorflow

The `capacity` argument of the function `tf.train.string_input_producer(string_tensor, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True, seed=None, capacity=32, shared_name=None, name=None)` is rather vague for me.

What does it mean to set the `capacity` argument here, does it have anything to do with the length of the argument `string_tensor`.
An example will be wonderful.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capacity is the size of the Queue, so in your example, the queue runner can enqueue up to 32 strings into the queue by default

Comment: Is 32 always enough? Or should we adapt to the size of the input or the nodes in the graph using the queue ?

Comment: It's essentially the size of prefetching buffer so it should be bigger if your data IO is highly unpredictable. There's a summary statistic exported from each input_producer to TensorBoard, something like "fraction_full", which shows how often it's 0. If it's usually zero, you want to add my queue runners, and if it's sometimes zero, then maybe your data consumption/production is unpredictable and buffer should be larger

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, could you elaborate on "prefetching buffer"? Further, are there any suggested number on capacity? Finally, to confirm, the capacity has nothing to do with the length of the `string_order`, is this correct?

Comment: Correct, "capacity" indicates the number of tensors that can be stored in the queue buffer. Prefetching means that fetching the data happens in parallel with the computation, in this case this is possible because filling the queue is done from a different thread than computations

Answer (score 0):

Capacity for [`string_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) is the maximum number of elements that a queue can hold at any given time. You should set the number high enough so that your model will not starve from not enough data. But if you will set it too high, the queue will consume too much memory.

The best number is model-specific and you can find it by trial and error. Start with a reasonably small number and check how often your queue is empty. Increase the buffer till you will not see an empty queue.

Comment: When the queue is empty, will it throw an OutOfRangeError immediately?